# using HTML code in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick

I would like to know how I can put HTML code inside a JavaScript function, like form code to display once button clicked.
I've learned how I can add rows to a table by a button click, but there is no HTML code involved in it which doesn't solve my problem. Here is the code I used :

```
<head>
  <script>
    function createRow() {
      var f = document.createElement("form");
      f.setAttribute('method', "post");
      f.setAttribute('action', "submit.php");

      var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
      i.setAttribute('type', "text");
      i.setAttribute('name', "username");

      var s = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
      s.setAttribute('type', "submit");
      s.setAttribute('value', "Submit");

      f.appendChild(i);
      f.appendChild(s);

      //and some more input elements here
      //and dont forget to add a submit button

      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
      var table1 = document.getElementById("table1");

      var newRow = table1.insertRow(3);
      var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
      newCell.innerHTML = "Fe";
      newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
      newCell.innerHTML = "Fi";
      newCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
      newCell.innerHTML = "Fo";
      newCell = newRow.insertCell(3);
      newCell.innerHTML = "Fum";
      document.write("<h1>Out with the old - in with the new!</h1>");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1>
    Editing HTML Tables
    </h1>
    <table id="table1" border="2">
      <tr>
        <td>Fe</td>
        <td>Fi</td>
        <td>Fo</td>
        <td>Fum</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fe</td>
        <td>Fi</td>
        <td>Fo</td>
        <td>Fum</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fe</td>
        <td>Fi</td>
        <td>Fo</td>
        <td>Fum</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Add a new row" onclick="createRow()">
  </center>
</body>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to use html code instead in my Javascript function ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I am not wrong you would like create a new row after click on 'add a new row' button?

Comment: What is expected result ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer . Nop, i have already tried creating a new row, what i want is to put html code in javascript code in order to display a form on click in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You already wrote the script for creating the new row, You just need append it in your table by this line.

`document.getElementById('table1').appendChild(newRow);`

And also comment out the line starts with `document.write(......)`

```js
function createRow() {
  var f = document.createElement("form");
  f.setAttribute('method', "post");
  f.setAttribute('action', "submit.php");

  var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
  i.setAttribute('type', "text");
  i.setAttribute('name', "username");

  var s = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
  s.setAttribute('type', "submit");
  s.setAttribute('value', "Submit");

  f.appendChild(i);
  f.appendChild(s);

  //and some more input elements here
  //and dont forget to add a submit button

  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
  var table1 = document.getElementById("table1");

  var newRow = table1.insertRow(3);
  var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  newCell.innerHTML = "Fe";
  newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
  newCell.innerHTML = "Fi";
  newCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
  newCell.innerHTML = "Fo";
  newCell = newRow.insertCell(3);
  newCell.innerHTML = "Fum";
  document.getElementById('table1').appendChild(newRow);
  //document.write("<h1>Out with the old - in with the new!</h1>");
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>
Editing HTML Tables
</h1>
  <table id="table1" border="2">
    <tr>
      <td>Fe</td>
      <td>Fi</td>
      <td>Fo</td>
      <td>Fum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fe</td>
      <td>Fi</td>
      <td>Fo</td>
      <td>Fum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fe</td>
      <td>Fi</td>
      <td>Fo</td>
      <td>Fum</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Add a new row" onclick="createRow()">
</center>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The exemple i put is what i already can do, but it's not what i need. In fact what i need is to display a form on click in an html page without loosing the content that is already there. In other words i want to add content to the same page i'm in.

Answer (score 0):

You can store html in a string, and then use that string to set html

```
var html = '<form>'+
    '<input type="text">'+
    '</form>';

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

But doing that way can be a maintenance nightmare if needing to use a lot of html.

You can hide html until you are ready for it to be shown

**CSS**

```
.hide {
   display:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="hide" id="myForm">
   <input type="text">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector("#someBtn").addEventListener("click",function(){
   document.querySelector("#myForm").classList.remove("hide");
});
```

---

Or put the html into a script tag, give the script tag custom type value so that the browser does not try to execute it as javascript. Then create your element with the html and then append it where needed

**HTML**

```
<head>
   <script id="formTemplate" type="my/template">
      <form>
         <input type="text">
      </form>
   </script>
</head>
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector("#someButton").addEventListener("click",function(){
   var html = document.querySelector("#formTemplate").textContent;
   var container = document.createElement("div");
   container.id = "MyFormContainer";
   container.innerHTML = html;
   document.body.appendChild(container);
});
```

---

Or just keep your html in a separate file and use an ajax request to fetch it and then use it as needed (using jQuery to do ajax request to make example small)

**somefile.html**

```
<form>
   <input type="text">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery.get("somefile.html").then(function(html){
   document.body.innerHTML = html;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. what i need is to display new content in the same page in addition to the content that is already there. However using document.body.innerHTML replaces the existing content with new one .

Comment: @ghrs That is just an example, replace that with whatever you are using

Comment: I know, it's just that i tried the first solution with the code in String html and it displays new content in the page without keeping the old one which is not what i need. document.body.innerHTML changes the content of the page completely.

Comment: @ghrs, Thats why I said it was an example and you replace that with what you need. Replace `document.body.innerHTML` with whatever you are wanting to put your html into, for example if you were wanting to put the html into a div and your div was in a variable named `myDiv` it would be `myDiv.innerHTML = html`